# need help on sending authentication request to server from web page

Tags: java, php, html, cgi

Hi guys this is my first post.

I want to send authentication request from my site to server enabling session while redirecting to other page using HTML or PHP or any thing related. 
so far i have set up a redirector on my server to my directory page on my site after login from server , but as soon as i login on my server it redirects to my page but sends me back from my site to server login page without any logs generated on my server 
i was wondering if i could enable session from my web page using form and PHP 
my server uses login.cgi
server is on HTTPS and site is on HTTP 
hoping to get help really getting frustrated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think according to your question, you haven't added a session handler yet to your pages. you need to add something like following code to the page that you are redirecting after successfully log-in,

```
   session_start();
   if(!isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_USER'])){
  header('location:../index.php');
```

}

In your Login Page, you need to add a session handler something like this,

```
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_USER']) && !empty($_SESSION['LOGIN_USER'])){
      header('location:../members/members_area.php');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man worked after modifying a little, really appreciate your help thanks again

Answer (score -1):

You can use Session Management concept of java, Please refer this link,
[Session Management in Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_session_tracking.htm)

In java you have to maintain Session in this.